# Ordered list in HTML that is numbered using odd numbers

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

Using `<ol type="1">` in HTML, I can get an ordered list to look like this:

1. I like cheese
2. Cookies are nice
3. Cream is good
   ...

How would I use `<ol>` to get an ordered list to only have odd numberings, like this?

1.I like cheese

3.Food is nice

5.I wish upon a star...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this can be achieved with normal ordered lists because [the only attributes available seem to be the following](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) (even including HTML5):

- type (indicates the numbering type)
- start (indicates the starting value)
- reversed (indicates whether the list is in reversed order)

But it can be achieved using CSS counters like in the below snippet. CSS counters is not a new thing and [has very good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters).

---

Implementing this with counters is pretty simple and only needs the following steps:

- Create (reset) a counter using the `counter-reset` property at the parent. The [`counter-reset`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-properties) property generally takes the name of the counter and the starting value as parameters. Here, I have used -1 as the starting value because at every `li` the increment should be by 2 and the start value needs to be 1 (so -1+2 = 1).
- Increment the counter's value by 2 every time a `li` is encountered. This makes the counter to have only odd numbered values. Again the [`counter-increment`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#counter-properties) property also generally takes 2 parameters - one is counter name and the other is the value by which it should be incremented.
- Display the counter's value before the list item using the `:before` pseudo-element and `content` property.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: odd-numbers -1;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: odd-numbers 2;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(odd-numbers) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

---

Another option without setting -1 as the start value would be to use the `li:first-child` selector and increment the counter only by 1 (default value and so it needn't be specified in `counter-increment`). For the rest of the `li` we can increment it by 2.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: odd-numbers;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:first-child {
  counter-increment: odd-numbers;
}
li {
  counter-increment: odd-numbers 2;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(odd-numbers) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: You could also use an adjacent selector and start the counter at 1. [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/oxcL2zth/).

Comment: Yup @Ricky_Ruiz. Very nice idea. Didn't think of that :D

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use this css rule, which hides the even elements.

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Then, have a blank `li` between the even rules:

```
<ol>
<li>1</li>
<li></li>
<li>3</li>
<li></li>
...
</ol>
```